# Equivalent of Java's Object type in C

Tags: c, object

Does the C programming language have anything similar to [Java's Object class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)? I realize that it would be difficult to implement something like this in a low-level language such as C, but I think it might be very useful nonetheless. If there is nothing like the `Object` type in C, then is there any way to mimic Java's `Object` type in C?

The main use case that I have in mind is the creation of arrays with multiple primitive types in C, to mimic an Object array in Java: `Object[] hasMultipleTypes = [3, "Hi!", 5.00];`

Comment: C doesn't have classes or objects at all.  Look into pointers and `void*`.

Comment: @SLaks That's why I'm searching for a way to mimic them in C, which doesn't support them. Would there be any way to create an array with multiple types, like this (as in Java)? `Object[] stuff = [1, "Hello world", 1.00]`

Comment: Object oriented programming is possible in C, but it involves lots of pointers and casts and looks a bit messy compared to languages designed for it. Look at some GTK+ code for examples.

Comment: I suppose I could use JSON strings to mimic objects in C. Would there be any better solution than this?

Comment: Uh, you could use C++.  But to my knowledge it has no base "Object" type class that others are derived from.  If you're into self-abuse you could use Objective-C, which has the NSObject class.

Comment: @HotLicks I think the most feasible solution in C would be to pass strings as arguments to functions, with the "type" of each string indicated like this: `string[] fakeMultipleTypes = ["int:3", "string:This should be converted to a string", "boolean:false"];`. Conversion functions could be written for each "type" of string, to convert each string to its corresponding type. Of course, it would then become necessary to convert each converted variable back to its string representation, so that it could be stored in the array again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic objects are not very complicated - set of data fields (`struct`) plus pointer to virtual methods table (VMT). Each member function takes pointer to "this" as first argument.

It is relatively straight forward to implement in C. I'd look for descriptions of original cross-compilers for C++ which were doing exactly this - convert object oriented code into plain C.

Approximate class:

```
struct MyClassVMT
 { 
    int *(method1)();
 }

struct MyClass 
{ 
  MyClassVMT* vmt;
  int field1;
}

void MyClass_Constructor(MyClass* pThis) { pThis.vmt = &_myClassVmt;}
void MyClass_nonVirtual (MyClass* pThis) {}
void MyClass_method1(MyClass* pThis) {}

MyClassVMT _myClassVmt;
_myClassVmt.mehtod1 = MyClass_method1;

// Usage
MyClass item;
MyClass_Constructor(&item);

MyClass_nonVirtual(&item); // non virtual method call
item.method1(&item); // virtual method call
```

Comment: There's a typo here: `Non_Virutal`.